# Why does there are three equations and two unknowns have solutions if determinant is zero?

Tags: linear-algebra

how to prove the equation system:

$a_1$$x$ + $b_1$$y$  = $p$

$a_2$$x$ + $b_2$$y$  = $q$

$a_3$$x$ + $b_3$$y$  = $r$

has unique solution for $x$ and $y$ if the determinant of the matrix
${$a_1, b_1, p$; $a_2, b_2, q$; $a_3, b_3, r$}$ is zero

ps: I just red a topic of two lines intersecting in 3d

Comment: What if $a_1, b_1, p;a_2, b_2, q;a_3, b_3, r$ all equal $0$? Then what about $x,y$?